# How to get the rating value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the clicked rating value in class called "input-star-rate" for sending to the database. Ratings are working fine. But my jQuery is not working.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<input class="rating form-control input-star-rate" name="rating" value="<?php echo $ratea; ?>" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.3" data-size="xs" style="display: none; text-align: center;"/>
```

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(function(){
    $(".input-star-rate").on("click", function(){
        var ratingValue = $this.value;
        alert(ratingValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: always keep an eye on firebug or other developer tools for any client side bugs or errors. They're a great deal helpful.

Comment: What did you think `$this` was, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
var ratingValue = $this.value;
```

Try

```
var ratingValue = $(this).val();   //Jquery syntax
```

OR

```
var ratingValue = this.value;    //Javascript syntax
```

OR

```
$(function(){
    $(".input-star-rate").on("click", function(){
        var $this = $(this); //  assign $(this) to $this
        var ratingValue = $this.val();  // use '.val()' as shown here
        alert(ratingValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Sudda...happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).delegate(".input-star-rate",'click',function()
    {
      var ratingValue = $(this).val();
        alert(ratingValue);
    });
```